# Agent key RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxx returned incorrect signature type - Win 10 PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, git, openssh

When doing a `git pull` I am getting the error in the title `agent key RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxx returned incorrect signature type`. Otherwise the key is working just fine, but I'm interested in fixing this and understanding why this is occurring.

I've removed the system32 OpenSSH directly from my environment path and now it is only OpenSSH-Win64 when generating the key or the when using SSH service for git.

Current git config:
`sshCommand = 'C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH-Win64\\ssh.exe'`

I generated the key using this command: `ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"`

I'm just not sure what is happening here. And I've run through all the other questions asked here that I thought might be relevant. If you need me to run any commands for more information or a log, etc. please just ask and I'll get what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most public-key algorithms in SSH, there is a fixed hash algorithm used for signatures.  For example, for Ed25519, it's SHA-512.  RSA keys (that is, `ssh-rsa`) traditionally used SHA-1, but that's no longer a secure option.

Recently, support for SHA-2 (SHA-256 and SHA-512) signatures with RSA were added, and there were additional components added to the SSH protocol and the agent protocol to support these.

If your connection negotiates an RSA key with a SHA-2 signature, but the OpenSSH agent you're using returns a SHA-1 signature (or, in some bizarre case I've never seen, a signature with the other SHA-2 algorithm), then you'll get this message.  *Usually* the server will let you continue the connection, but you're using a weaker algorithm, so you'll want to fix it.

If you're using a different program than your OpenSSH version's `ssh-agent` process, then you'll want to upgrade it to a fixed version that knows about SHA-2 RSA signatures.  Alternatively, you can just switch to using OpenSSH's `ssh-agent`.

As a final option, you can just use a different type of key.  Assuming the server you're using supports Ed25519 keys, they're a robust and secure option that won't have this problem.  You'd generate such a key with the same command, but with `-t ed25519` instead of `-t rsa`.

Comment: Thanks, changing to `ssh-keygen.exe -t ed25519 -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"` worked perfectly, it's no longer showing this warning when I do `git pull`

Comment: Just a note. For ed25519 there is no need to set the key size, as all Ed25519 keys are 256 bits. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Ed25519